# Why is jquery freaking out about this selector?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, json

I've got a ruby on rails application that's producing a json string and saving it in a div data attribute. This is the string in the ruby file before being rendered in teh browser:

```
'{"all":{"$(\'#condition_fields&nbsp;.table_form&nbsp;div[data-id=2]&nbspselect[data-attr=bar_type]\')":{"equal":"Baz"}}}'
```

The json string appears as follows when inspected in the browser:

```
data-dependencies="{"all":{"$('#condition_fields .table_form div[data-id=2] select[data-attr=bar_type]')":{"equal":"Baz"}}}"
```

A jQuery plugin consumes the selector in this string by calling eval on it. The selector, when output to the console by the jQuery plugin, looks like so:

```
$('#condition_fields .table_form div[data-id=2] select[data-attr=bar_type]')
```

I have yet to find a combination of escaping that produces a usable selector for jQuery. I either get

```
Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: #condition_fields .table_form&nbspdiv[data-id=2]&nbspselect[data-attr=bar_type]
```

or

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL
```

depending on how I feed the string (quoted or unquoted) into jQuery eval in teh console.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks!

Comment: can you consider replacing the expression "freak out"

Comment: I'm kinda shooting in the dark here, but what's the reason for using `&nbsp;` in the ruby file, rather than literal spaces?

Comment: Why is the JSON formatted like that? Can you change the way it's composed? As it is right now, you have the jquery statement as `key` of a object. That means you have to do some pretty dubious things to get anything useful out of it, like `eval` on a object's `key` that you can't reliably acquire.

Comment: Also, that jQuery code as `key` value is just asking for trouble in JSON parsers. [Jsonlint](http://jsonlint.com/) is throwing a `Parse error` at that point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Javascript doesn't like the non-breaking spaces. Instead of using `&nbsp;`, use `&#32;`.

Answer (score 1):

Your error show your selector : `#condition_fields .table_form&nbspdiv[data-id=2]&nbspselect[data-attr=bar_type]`.

As you can see, there's a non-breaking space. It is a special character and jQuery doesnt recognize it as a space.

Try deleting the spaces between `.table_form`, `div` and the `select` then input a true space.

In case you can't, you can always use the infamous converting method :

```
$('<div>').html(youString).text();
```

Comment: `"&nbsp;".replace(/\s/g, ' ');` --> `"&nbsp;"`. Or am I misinterpreting something here?

Comment: @Cerbrus It depend, since he said his output was `$('#condition_fields .table_form div[data-id=2] select[data-attr=bar_type]')`, `&nbsp;` are converted into a white space character. But yes, if they aren't converted, &nbsp will not be changed.

Comment: Replacing the &nbsp; in the console with spaces still produces the SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL error.

Replacing the &nbsp; in teh ruby produces a Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input error.